# Google feed api deprecated, How can i find rss feed of web site?

Tags: api, rss, feed, google-feed-api

I used Google Feed API for finding rss feeds of special keywords or websites, now this api deprecated, so i need alternative way for finding rss of website, I google it but i cannot find any good way..

Find rss from parsing html of website is not good for me because i want to find all rss from any subdomains of it.

For example in the past when with using Google Feed API i give ieee.org and get all rss like:

http://www.ieee.org/rss/index.html?feedId=News_Release

http://spectrum.ieee.org/rss/fulltext

http://spectrum.ieee.org/rss/blog/automaton/fulltext

and ....

So, Is there any api or services that i can find all of rss feeds of website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feedly's API could fit your requirements. See https://developer.feedly.com/v3/search/

Pass the site's domain name as query parameter and you'll get rss feed matches:
https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/search/feeds/?query=ieee.org

Answer (score 1):

You can use rss2json API to get feed data same as google feed API did.

```
var url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/feeds/news/8.xml"; //feed url
var xhr = createCORSRequest("GET","https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url="+url);
if (!xhr) {
  throw new Error('CORS not supported');
} else {
    xhr.send();
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
        var responseText = xhr.responseText;
        var result = JSON.parse(responseText);
        console.log(result);
    }
}
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

Comment: tanx for try to help me but i need rss url finder not rss to json method..!! please read my question again!